# class with unique_ptr problems

Tags: c++, c++11

When using emplace_back a constructor must exist for the parameters passed (k,v) thus I need the constructor below. However since I use unique_ptr it complains about not being able to access 'delete' which I believe means I'm doing something that allows me to have more then one pointer.

I can't figure out the syntax. How do I write this constructor the right way?

```
struct KV{ 
    unique_ptr<string> k, v;
    KV(){} 
    KV (unique_ptr<string> k_,unique_ptr<string> v_):k(move(k_)),v(move(v_)){} 
};
```

Comment: You're not new here, you should know better than to post a question missing stuff.  Show the entire error message.  Preferably, link to a short minimal self-contained example on ideone or another online compiler, so we have both the error message and the complete code causing it.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Does gcc or IDEONE support `emplace_back`? I know visual studio does so trying that didn't cross my mind and andy knew my syntax was correct and i was just calling it wrong

Comment: Yes, if you select C++11 mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor is OK. A possible problem is that you are not moving the two `unique_ptr`s when supplying them to your constructor:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct KV{
   unique_ptr<string> k, v;
   KV(){}
   KV (unique_ptr<string> k_,unique_ptr<string> v_):k(move(k_)),v(move(v_)){}
};

int main()
{
   unique_ptr<string> p1(new string());
   unique_ptr<string> p2(new string());

   // KV v(p1, p2); // ERROR!
   KV kv(move(p1), move(p2)); // OK

   vector<KV> v;    
   v.emplace_back(move(p1), move(p2)); // OK       
}
```

**UPDATE:**

When VS2012 was shipped, VC11 did not support variadic templates. The correct implementation of `emplace_back()` *should* be variadic, but MS provided a dummy one. When the CTP has been shipped, only the *compiler* has been updated with support for variadic templates, but the STL hasn't been updated. Therefore, you still get the error.

There is not much to do about this if you can't change your compiler, apart from waiting for the next release of the product to be shipped. In the meanwhile, avoid using `emplace_back()` and use `push_back()` instead.

Comment: This does not compile `ls.emplace_back(move(key), move(make_unique<string>(tempstring)));` but `KV(move(key), move(make_unique<string>(tempstring)))` does hmmm..... +1

Comment: @acidzombie24: could you be a bit more specific? How is `ls` declared? What is `key`?

Comment: key is `unqiue<string>` and ls is `vector<KV>&ls`

Comment: @acidzombie24: it works [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4a0p5k$7). What version of VC are you using? Do you have the CTP?

Comment: I have Nov2012 CTP. This doesnt work there. Darn. I'm going to see what I can do -edit-. That source definately doesnt compile for me :(

Comment: I think CTP doesn't help here because emplace_back needs to be updated in the standard library.

Comment: @acidzombie24: It's a problem with MS's implementation of the STL, I'll extend my answer. There's not much you can do about it, just avoid `emplace_back`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned what container you're trying to `emplace_back` into, but assuming it is a `vector`, if your `KV` struct is really that simple, there's no need to declare any constructors. Just use aggregate initialization.

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct KV
{
   unique_ptr<string> k, v;
   // KV(){}
   // KV (unique_ptr<string> k_,unique_ptr<string> v_):k(move(k_)),v(move(v_)){}
};

int main()
{
   unique_ptr<string> p1(new string());
   unique_ptr<string> p2(new string());

   KV v{move(p1), move(p2)}; // initialize an instance
                             // this step is not necessary, you can skip it

   vector<KV> vec;

   vec.emplace_back(KV{move(v.k), move(v.v)});
}
```

Comment: I would LOVE to do this but MSVC doesn't support `{}` yet. Although this IS what I am trying to do

Comment: @acidzombie24 MSVC shouldn't have any problem with this, it's aggregate initialization, something that's been around pre-C++11. You're thinking about braced-init-lists used for uniform initialization syntax.

Comment: If you're using `emplace_back()` though, constructing a `KV` should not be needed. You should just pass the arguments

Comment: @AndyProwl I added a comment in the code right before you posted that :)

Comment: @Praetorian: But you're still doing it in the call to `emplace_back()` :-)

Comment: @Andy Can't get it to compile unless I do that. Note that I've changed his `KV` struct to being an aggregate. Is there a way to `emplace_back` without creating that temp `KV`?

Comment: In C++11, yes.  In the broken implementation of `emplace_back` acidzombie is using, no.

Comment: @acidzombie24 You're right, I can't get this code to work on VS2012

Comment: My compiler isnt up to par so nevermind. I'll just get everything working then clean it up later

Comment: @Praetorian: This is because of MS's implementation of the STL. It is not based on variadic template support introduced with the CTP, and `emplace_back()` has a kind of dummy implementation.